# MongoDB use $last with $cond

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there any way to get the last non-zero value in an aggregation. Is that possible?

Scenario:

I have an events collection, in which I store all the events from users. I want to fetch the list of users with last purchased items cost is $1.99 and logged in at least once last week.

My events collection will have records like

```
{_id:ObjectId("58af54d5ab7df73d71822708"),uid:1,event:"login"}
{_id:ObjectId("58db7189296fdedde1c04bc1"),uid:2,event:"login"}
{_id:ObjectId("5888419bfa4b69dc4af7c76c"),uid:2,event:"purchase",amount:3}
{_id:ObjectId("5888419bfa4b69dc4af7d45c"),uid:1,event:"purchase",amount:1.9}
{_id:ObjectId("5888819bfa4b69dc4af7c76c"),uid:1,event:"custom",type:3,value:2}
```

What am trying to do:

```
  db.events.aggregate([{
      {
        $group: {
          _id: uid,
          last_login: {
            $max: {
              $cond: [{
                $eq: ['$event', 'login']
              }, '$_id', 0]
            }
          },
          last_amount: {
            $last: {
              $cond: [{
                $eq: ['$event', 'login']
              }, '$_id', 0]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }, {
      $match: {
        last_purchase: {
          $gte: ObjectId("58af54d50000000000000000")
        },
        last_amount: 1.9
      }
    }])
```

which obviously will fail because last will have 0 as the last item.

The output am expecting is

```
{_id:1,last_login:_id:ObjectId("58af54d5ab7df73d71822708"),last_amount:1.9}
```

The query is system generated. Please help.

Comment: Added sample documents and expected output

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you cannot modify the behaviour of $last using $cond. i.e. 'not the last entry because of a criteria'.
There are few alternatives that you could try:

- Alter your [document schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/) for the access pattern, especially if this is a frequently used query in your application. You should utilise the schema as a leverage to optimise your application queries.
- Use one of the [MongoDB supported drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/drivers/) to process the expected outcome.
- Depending on the use case, you could execute 2 separate aggregation queries; first query all the users uid that logged in at least once last week, and second to query only those users that have the last purchased item value of $1.99.

Comment: Hey Ivan, 
Thank you. But I found an alternative way for doing this. I used $push in grouping and $slice and $setDifference in $project

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.Instead of $last, I used $push in the $group and added $slice with $setDifference in $project to remove null values. The query will now look something like

```js
    db.events.aggregate([{
          {
            $group: {
              _id: uid,
              last_login: {
                $max: {
                  $cond: [{
                    $eq: ['$event', 'login']
                  }, '$_id', 0]
                }
              },
              last_amount: {
                $push: {
                  $cond: [{
                    $eq: ['$event', 'login']
                  }, '$_id', null]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
    {$project:{last_login:{$slice:[{$setDifference,'$last_login',[null]},-1,1]}}}
    , {
          $match: {
            last_purchase: {
              $gte: ObjectId("58af54d50000000000000000")
            },
            last_amount: 1.9
          }
        }])
```

Comment: Smart! Thanks! =)